# Angular-Translate doesn't work in tag attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, attributes, angular-translate

I us `angular-translate` in my project. I defined some key like:

```
{
"paging":{
   "first":"First",
   "last":"Last",
    "next":"Next2",
    "pre":"Previous"
   }
}
```

and I use it:

```
<uib-pagination first-text="{{'paging.first' | translate}}" 
                last-text="{{'paging.last' | translate}}"
                next-text="{{'paging.next' | translate}}"          
                previous-text="{{'paging.pre' | translate}}">
</uib-pagination>
```

Also I use `$translatePartialLoader.addPart('module');` in top of controller, but when run app in browser, show me like this:
[image: angular-translate attribute]

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but I'm not sure what you're trying to do is even possible. The closest I've found is documented [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translateNamespace). I'd be interested to know if this is possible myself..

Comment: Hi @Ankh, when I use translate like `<p>{{'paging.next' | translate}}</p>` in html everythings is OK, but when put it in html tag attribute like `previous-text="{{'paging.pre' | translate}}">`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment further and sculpt an answer, I don't think it's possible to use namespaces in the translate filter. [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764496/angular-translate-filter-ignores-namespace).

An alternative is to generate the translations in your controller first using the `$translate` service and assigning the values onto the `$scope`. e.g.

```
$scope.firstText = $translate.instant('paging.first');
```

Then..

```
<uib-pagination first-text="{{ firstText }}"...
```

I created a crude plunker to [demonstrate this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tg7QUh98uRtkzWzkU6US?p=preview).